# Consultar por mes

Tags: php, sql, date

Tengo una tabla el cual muestra una factura de condominio mensual, pero requiero que muestre los gastos que se registraron en el ultimo mes solamente en la base de datos y no todos los gastos que estan, aqui esta como esta conformada la tabla gasto_g de la base de datos[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui esta el codigo que estoy usando para hacer la consulta pero me muestra como error Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

```html
                       require_once('./conexion.php');
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM gasto_g WHERE created_at BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND NOW() ORDER BY id_gasto_g DESC;" ;
  $res = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
  while($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
                        ?>   
 


 

    
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $resultado['id_gasto_g']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $resultado['descripcion']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $resultado['monto']; ?></td>

                            <td>
```

Comment: has probado el query directamente en la base de datos?

Comment: no funciona :/ correctamente. ¿Alguna idea de como hacer el query?

Comment: entonces cambia totalmente la pregunta.. pregunta sobre el query. es lo primero que se prueba, siempre...

Comment: el query esta realizado mas algo esta mal realizado que no lo realiza de forma adecuada, para responder de esa forma mejor has caso omiso y listo

Comment: Puede estar ocurriendo que: **1.** Algo falla en `require_once('./conexion.php');` Ese archivo debe crear un objeto `$conexion` válido. En ese sentido es bueno controlar que dicho objeto se crea o si es nulo. Para depurar haz un `var_dump($conexion);`  **2.** Hay un error aquí: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM gasto_g WHERE created_at BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND NOW() ORDER BY id_gasto_g DESC;" ;` Puedes imprimir esa cadena: `echo $sql`, copiarla, pegarla en el manejador de base de datos directamente y verificar si arroja resultados. De todos modos necesitas más control del código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La consulta es sintácticamente correcta, exceptuando que algún campo este mal referenciado:

```
SELECT * FROM gasto_g 
WHERE created_at BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND NOW()
ORDER BY id_gasto_g DESC;
```

El problema que indicas:

> mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given, la linea X

Es por que `mysqli_fetch_array()` esta recibiendo un `boleano` en lugar de un objeto `mysqli_result`, la variable `$res` de tu código es **false** ya que  `mysqli_query()` **Retorna FALSE en caso de error**.

Valores devueltos [mysqli_query()](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php)

> Retorna FALSE en caso de error. Si una consulta del tipo SELECT, SHOW,
>   DESCRIBE o EXPLAIN es exitosa, mysqli_query() retornará un objeto
>   mysqli_result. Para otras consultas exitosas de mysqli_query()
>   retornará TRUE.

¿A qué puede ser debido que `mysqli_query` falle?

1. La `$conexion` o link pasado como primer argumento no es válido o falló.
2. La consulta proporcionada no es válida o falló.
3. El string de la consulta supera `max_allowed_packet` (cosa muy rara).

Revisa los 2 primeros puntos, suguro el problemas esta en la conexión o en la consulta.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que este error es cuando ocurre en la consulta, en este caso en la construcción del `select`, al final escribes `ORDER BY Id` pero no existe el campo id, no se si quieres ordenarlo por id_usuario o id_gasto_g, prueba a ver....

Comment: no funciona, le quito el order by y sigue el mismo error

Comment: entiendo que has quitado toda esta parte: "ORDER BY id_gasto_g DESC;" quita también el ";" de dentro las comillas, porque realmente por lo que recuerdo no sirve.

Comment: Si esto sigue sin funcionar comprueba que el archivo conexión este bien ubicado y que lo de dentro este bien construido, porque la consulta a mi me sale bien.

Comment: while($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){ da error en esta linea

Comment: ya, pero el problema es por el parámetro $res que no sale bien.

Comment: ya he realizado otras consultas asi con las que no requieren fecha y el $res funciona

Comment: la consulta la he probado en una tabla y funciona perfectamente, el resto si no me equivoco, no veo error entonces tiene que estar el problema en el archivo de conexión que la ruta esté indicada bien o que lo de dentro esté correcto

Comment: prueba mysqli_error($conexion) a ver si te da pistas

Comment: nada :/ que extraño mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given, la linea que indica es while($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){

Comment: pero como te he dicho antes no hagas caso que indique esa línea esto es porque el parametro res no es correcto, es decir, esta línea mysqli_query($conexion,$sql) no arroja un resultado correcto, ya sea por que el valor de conexion es incorrecto o por que sql es incorrecto. Pero puedo decir, porque lo he probado que sql es correcto los posibles errores eran el id de order by y el ; dentro de las comillas, si quitas eso esta bien. Así que.... repasa lo de conexion